# Image not showing react native image component

Tags: reactjs

image not showing in react-native image component
here my code

```
class Xyz extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
    <View>
      <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri:'{this.props.new}'}}
        />
        </View>

    );

  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your ```this.props.new```? how is it passed and what is its value? Any errors?

Comment: <Xyz new='https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'/>

Comment: my component class is
class Xyz extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
    <View>
      <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri:'{this.props.new}'}}
        />
        </View>

    );
  
  }
}

=========================
export default class LotsOfGreetings extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
       <Xyz new='https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Comment: can you try this? ```source={{uri:this.props.new}}```

Comment: ohh thank u very much it works thanks a lot

Comment: could u plese explain it abt that error

Comment: see below, glad it helped

Comment: please read carefully react native docs about Image view https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image

Comment: ohh got it thank u

Comment: For me, I was not paying attention to the image style. I was using maxHeight and maxWidth instead of simple height and width. Hope that helps somebody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant this.

```
class Xyz extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                <Image
                    style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
                    source={{ uri: this.props.new }}
                />
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

If you do

```
{
  uri: '{this.props.new}'
}
```

You are treating `{this.prop.new}` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this : `source={{this.props.new}}` in your `render()` method

```
<View>
  <Image 
      style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
      source={{uri: props.imageUri }} />
</View>
```